# NAO robot grasps a ball on the ground

Tags: nao-robot

I create a timeline on Choregraph,and turn to the animation mode.I have trouble in making NAO crouch and making its hand able to reach the ball on the ground.How to record every gesture,such as intervals between two gestures,how many gesture I should record.Meanwhile,the robot often falls down...How can I adjust the gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choregraphe's animation mode helped you design grossly the movement of the robot, but it is up to you refine the result by spacing the key frames properly, and tuning the movement to maintain the balance.

Robot animation requires time and skill, and includes specific challenges :

- you may have to move the robot to positions that are not balanced, which the robot requires too much strength to maintain, resulting in hot joints*, loss of strength, or the robot falling. Hence you need to be able to carry the robot regularly to record or test the robot's position.
- the positions are irremediably mechanically constrained.
- real joints are imperfect, have limited maximum strength and speed, and have play.
- real world have real obstacles, and the robot tries to avoid them, altering the desired trajectories.

*When you get hot joints, just let the robot sit for 2 minutes, you do not need to reboot it.

Comment: Now,the issue is that it says "I can't move anymore,some of my motors are too hot in my left leg,please let me rest for a while" when I adjust the gesture.It occurs too often to record next gesture,I have to reboot the robot which takes about 3~5 minutes(let it rest may take more time).How can I avoid this issue?